# After upgrade to iOS 11.3 web app does not show full screen per apple-mobile-web-app-capable

Tags: ios, mobile-safari

I have a web app that contains the meta

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

Before iOS 11.3, when "added to Home Screen" it would then open like a standalone app without the navigation bar.

After 11.3 it now opens with the navigation bar in the browser.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After hours of troubleshooting I found the following that might be helpful for others.

For Android/Chrome compatibility, I already had the following in my html file:

```
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
```

The manifest.json had no `"display": "standalone"` entry, it just had icons and name defined. It appears that before 11.3 the file was ignored by safari but now it is considered and has precedence over the meta tag `apple-mobile-web-app-capable`.  Since [the default for `display:` is browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest), the app was opened inside a browser with a navigation bar.

When I added the line `"display": "standalone"` in the manifest file the problem went away.

Comment: Thanks, you saved me from hours of weekend debugging. "display": "standalone" solved the problem.

Comment: If it weren't for SO we would have dropped iOS as IE5 a long time ago.

Comment: @terrymorse I already had "display": "standalone" in my manifest.json but still having the problem, any idea? The manifest.json is loaded for sure because the title and icon are used when doing Add to Homescreen.

Comment: @riper - After the iOS 12.2 release, I saw several problems in standalone mode. My brute force fix was to eliminate the <link rel="manifest"> tag from the html file, and using three "apple-mobile-web-app.*" meta tags. Not ideal.

Comment: @terrymorse After your change, did it continue to work for Android?

Comment: @riper - I didn't test it on Android, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this as well.  @gae123 is right about the manifest.json.  You may also try removing any conflicting apple specific meta tags which can be seen here:  [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002051-CH3-SW1) .  I also found that "display": "fullscreen" in the json was what it took, your mileage may vary.

Comment: Spot on self answer. You have already saved a lot of us a day or more.