# iOS PWA "Add to Home Screen" - DISABLE Full Screen Mode

Tags: ios, web-applications, mobile-website, progressive-web-apps

I have a PWA that is cross-platform but am running into some issues on iOS 11.3+.

When a user executes "Add to Homescreen" I would like to KEEP the menu bar (refresh, back, forward buttons). i.e. I don't want full-screen mode because I don't want to have to create my own refresh and back buttons.

I've followed the advice at https://medium.com/@firt/dont-use-ios-web-app-meta-tag-irresponsibly-in-your-progressive-web-apps-85d70f4438cb .  Most other articles I've found are significantly out-of-date on the subject.

I've removed the "apple-mobile-web-app-capable" meta tag but it doesn't work. I've also tried setting the value to "no".

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="no">
```

How do I PREVENT the "Add to Homescreen" on iOS 11 from going to into full-screen mode?

Comment: Have you manage to check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48774142/after-upgrade-to-ios-11-3-web-app-does-not-show-full-screen-per-apple-mobile-web)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remove the meta tag itself:

Make sure you also are removing the apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style meta tag also otherwise it may be thinking that you want it in full-screen mode by stating you want the status bar.

If you are still having problems after this and clearing all your history and cache, check out [Apple’s article on PWAs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html) and try to remove the extra meta tags that are inserted in your website.

Answer (score 1):

If you find that your PWA still remains full-screen after removing:

```html
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

Double-check your `manifest.json` for `"display": "standalone"` and remove it also.