# PWA not opening in full screen mode on iphone/ipad

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, mobile-safari, progressive-web-apps

I went through several articles related to PWA on ios but still not able to figure out why I am seeing address bar after adding an app to the home screen. I would be glad if someone could help me with this.

**meta tags in my index file**

```
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="manifest" href="./assets/manifest.json">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
```

**Manifest File**

```
{
    "short_name": "Dashboard",
    "name": "Dashboard",
    "icons": [
      {
        "src": "logo.png",
        "sizes": "512x512",
        "type": "image/png"
      }
    ],
    "start_url": "/home",
    "display": "standalone",
    "theme_color": "#000",
    "background_color": "#000"
  }
```

Comment: You may check the workaround given in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48774142/after-upgrade-to-ios-11-3-web-app-does-not-show-full-screen-per-apple-mobile-web). Since you are already using `"display": "standalone"` in the manifest file, you may try `"display": "fullscreen"` and see if it works.

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone stumble on this article. As of 04-2020 iOS does not read the manifest file to set the PWA screen mode. Instead one needs to add their `meta` tags:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

For viewing the app in full screen mode. And:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
```

For setting the status bar the same color as page `<body>`. There are other options available: `black` and `white`.

Comment: Do you have a reference link to this?